# How to open folder with an already running Total Commander in BATCH?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, total-commander

I want to create a **BATCH** file, which **opens** a specified **folder with Total Commander**. But there are 2 possibility:

1. if there is no running TotalCommander --> a **new** TotalCommander will
   start and open the folder
2. if there is an **already running** TotalCommander --> open the folder with
   the running TC, and do not start a new TotalCommander

I have a code, which opens the folder with TotalCommander, but it always start a new TotalCommander, and not using the running one:

```
@echo off
SET totalc="C:\totalcmd\TOTALCMD.EXE"
set folder="C:\temp"
ECHO opening %folder% with %totalc%
%totalc% %folder%
ECHO opened
```

Is there any solution, to resolve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal
    set "totalc=C:\totalcmd\TOTALCMD.EXE"
    set "folder=C:\temp"
    echo opening "%folder%" with "%totalc%"
    "%totalc%" /O /T /R="%folder%"
    echo opened
```

From the [documentation](http://www.ghisler.ch/wiki/index.php/Command_line_parameters)

> */O* If Total Commander is already running, activate it and pass the path(s) in the command line to that instance (overrides the settings
>   in the configuration dialog to have multiple windows)
>
> */R=* Set path right window
>
> */T* Opens the passed dir(s) in new tab(s) (for usage with /O)

Comment: excellent! I will drink a pálinka tonight to your health! en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A1linka

Comment: when I'm trying to run this form `.bash_profile` script or from `git bash cli` - it opens new window, from `.bat` works like a charm, do you have any idea why is this happens? my command is ` c:\\totalcmd\\TOTALCMD64.EXE /O /T /S /L=c:\\users\\`

Comment: works as charm with dashed params c:\\totalcmd\\TOTALCMD64.EXE -o -t -s -l=c:\\users\`